# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'

Tags: android, xml, actionbarsherlock

I am facing this annoying problem with the Action Bar Sherlock (ABS) in a 'theme.xml' file of my Android Library Project that I am creating and I cannot really find a solution to it.

I have referenced the ABS library correctly into my Library Project and the build target of my Library project is currently set to 19 with the minSdkVersion being 8. I have used the ABS before but this is kinda strange.

Here is my theme file:

```
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">

    <!-- Set style for Action Bar (affects tab bar too) -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

I also tried it without the '@style' tag:

parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"

I have checked out various posts and tried the answers mentioned but it does not seem to work.
Is this because I am creating a Library project? Or Is there a silly issue that I am overlooking?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use AppCompat why use actionbarsherlock

Comment: @Raghunandan, I have existing code that will have to be changed in case I discard the ABS, which is not an option right now. What can be the problem with this though?

Comment: actually actionbarsherlock is no more supported by the authors. aNd android has Appcompat for backward compatibility and hence its better you switch to AppCompat. Have you referenced actionbarsherlock??

Comment: @Raghunandan, I have referenced the ActionBarSherlock. But if 'AppCompact' does serve the purpose, I will go for it. Thank you for the information regarding ABS.

Comment: Does autocomplete show any of those themes?

Comment: @Raghunandan, as mentioned I am using this Action Bar in my Library project. So will it be a problem if a Host Project has an entirely different Action Bar? Like, will there be a conflict as I am using a separate theme for the Action Bar while the Host may have a different one. Is it possible/recommended to provide an Action Bar with the Library? I want the User to feel like he is accessing my App while what is happening is the Host App is calling my Library Activity.

Comment: @Mgamerz, I restarted Eclipse... It works now. Strange.

Comment: That's Eclipse for ya.